# I am stuck in callback hell.Can anyone suggest best method to do the job?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, callback

I am making an Uber-like app for trucks after fetch trucks location I have to find matching trucks with a posted load. But I am stuck in callback hell. Can you please mention best method to do the job efficiently and good performance at the same time.I am creating backend in express.js and using two databases Mysql and MongoDB.Any help is highly appriciated.

```
        const express = require('express');
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const mysql = require('mysql');
    const request = require('request');
    const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
    const cors = require('cors');
    const moment = require('moment');
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');

    mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/Location");
    const mongoConn = mongoose.connection;

    mongoConn.on('connected',function () {
        console.log("mongo connected");
    });
    mongoConn.on('disconnected',function () {
        console.log("mongo disconnected");
    });
    mongoConn.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
    mongoConn.once('open', function() {
        console.log("mongo connection opened");
    });
    const LocationSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        truck_id:Number,
        user_id:Number,
        longitude:Number,
        latitude:Number,
        created_at:Number,
        status:Number
    });
    const Location = mongoose.model('Location',LocationSchema);
    const app = express();
    app.listen(3002  ,()=> {
        console.log('server is listening at port 3002');
    });
    app.use(cors());

    app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
        next();
    });
    app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
        extended: true
    }));

    const db = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : '127.0.0.1',
        user     : 'root',
        password : '',
        database : 'truck'
    });

    db.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
            return;
        }
        console.log('connected as id ' + db.threadId);
    });

    app.get('/view-trucks',verifyUser,(req,res)=>{

        let truck_ids = [];
        let truck_locations;
        let load_id = req.query.id;
        let sql = 'SELECT * FROM tr_post_load WHERE id = '+ db.escape(load_id);
        db.query(sql,function (error, results, fields) {
            if(error){console.log('error is '+error);res.status(200).send({status:'error'});throw error;}
            if(results.length > 0){
                let load_from_lat = results[0].from_lat;
                let load_from_long = results[0].from_long;
                let load_to_lat = results[0].to_lat;
                let load_to_long = results[0].to_long;

                let find_Trucks_sql =  'SELECT * FROM tr_truck WHERE user_id != '+results[0].user_id+' AND truck_capacity_id = ? AND body_type_id = ? AND truck_length_id = ?';

                db.query(find_Trucks_sql,[results[0].truck_capacity_id,results[0].body_type_id,results[0].truck_length_id],function (error, results, fields) {

                    if (error) {console.log('error is ' + error);res.status(200).send({status: 'error'});throw error;}
                    if(results.length > 0) {
                        for (let a = 0; a <= results.length; a++) {
                            if(typeof results[a] === 'object'){
                                truck_ids.push(results[a].id);
                            }
                        }
                        console.log("truck ids are "+truck_ids);
                        if(truck_ids.length > 0){
                            // fetch location from mongodb
                            let locationQuery = Location.find({truck_id:{$in:truck_ids},status:1}).lean();
                            locationQuery.exec(function (err,locations) {
                                if (err){console.log("mongo error is "+err);res.status(200).send({status: 'error'});}
                                truck_locations = locations;
                                if(truck_locations.length > 0) {
                                    console.log("truck length ay 847 is " + truck_locations.length);
                                    for (let i = 0; i <= truck_locations.length; i++) {

                                        if (typeof truck_locations[i] === "object") {
                                            console.log("my truck value at line 849 is " + truck_locations[i]);

                                            let diff = findTimeDiff(truck_locations[i].created_at);
                                            console.log("time difference is " + diff);
                                            if (diff) {
                                                if (truck_locations[i].latitude !== null && truck_locations[i].longitude !== null) {
                                                    let dist = distance(load_from_lat, load_from_long, truck_locations[i].latitude, truck_locations[i].longitude);
                                                    if (dist !== null) {
                                                        console.log("if dist truck id is  " + truck_locations[i].truck_id);
                                                        let truck_routes_sql = "SELECT * FROM tr_route WHERE truck_id = " + db.escape(truck_locations[i].truck_id);
                                                        db.query(truck_routes_sql, function (err, truck_routes, fields) {
                                                            if (err) {console.log("error while fetching truck routes is " + err);throw err;}

                                                            console.log("truck routed are " + JSON.stringify(truck_routes));
                                                            console.log("my truck value at line 868 is " + truck_locations[i]);
                                                            if (truck_routes.length > 0) {
                                                                for (let j = 0; j <= truck_routes.length; j++) {
                                                                    console.log("current trucks route is " + JSON.stringify(truck_routes[j]));
                                                                    if (typeof truck_routes[j] === "object" && truck_routes[j].from_lat !== null && truck_routes[j].from_long !== null) {
                                                                        let route_distance_from = distance(load_to_lat, load_to_long, truck_routes[j].from_lat, truck_routes[j].from_long);
                                                                        let route_ditance_to = distance(load_to_lat, load_to_long, truck_routes[j].to_lat, truck_routes[j].to_long);
                                                                        if (route_distance_from !== null || route_ditance_to !== null) {
                                                                            console.log("i am in truck route distance at line 869 and truck is " + JSON.stringify(truck_locations[i]));
                                                                            let find_truck_sql = "SELECT * FROM tr_truck WHERE id = " + db.escape(truck_routes[j].truck_id);
                                                                            db.query(find_truck_sql, function (error, truck, fields) {
                                                                                if (err) {
                                                                                    console.log("error while fetching truck routes is " + err);
                                                                                    throw err;
                                                                                }
                                                                                // console.log("truck on line 874 is  "+JSON.stringify(truck[0])+"and truck length is "+truck.length);
                                                                                if (truck.length > 0 && typeof truck[0] !== "undefined") {
                                                                                    console.log("final truck found  on line 884 is  " + JSON.stringify(truck[0]));
                                                                                    console.log("885 mytruck at position "+i+" is "+JSON.stringify(truck_locations[i]));

                                                                                    truck_locations[i].truck = truck[0];

                                                                                    console.log("after adding object and truck is " + JSON.stringify(truck_locations));
                                                                                }
                                                                            });
                                                                        } else {
                                                                            // mytrucks.splice(i,1);
                                                                        }
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            } else {
                                                                // truck_locations.splice(i, 1);
                                                                console.log("i is " + i + " no routes found and my_trucks are now  " + JSON.stringify(truck_locations));
                                                            }
                                                        });
                                                    } else {
                                                        //  mytrucks.splice(i,1);
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            } else {
                                                // mytrucks.splice(i,1);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                res.status(200).send(truck_locations);
                                //end of location
                            });
                        }else{
                            res.status(200).send("no truck found");
                        }
                    }else{
                        res.status(200).send("no truck found");
                    }
                });
            }else{
                res.status(200).send({status:'notExist'});
            }

        });
    });

    function distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
        let p = 0.017453292519943295;    // Math.PI / 180
        let c = Math.cos;
        let a = 0.5 - c((lat2 - lat1) * p)/2 +
            c(lat1 * p) * c(lat2 * p) *
            (1 - c((lon2 - lon1) * p))/2;

        return 12742 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a)); // 2 * R; R = 6371 km
    }

    function findTimeDiff(truck_created_at) {
        let truck_time = truck_created_at;
        truck_time = moment(truck_time);
        let nowTime = moment().utcOffset("+05:30").toDate().getTime();
        nowTime = moment(nowTime);
        return nowTime.diff(truck_time, "minutes");
    }
```

Comment: This isn't callback hell.  This is callback apocalypse.

Comment: Try https://javascript.info/async-await

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a package [`promise-mysql`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-mysql), which has wrapped `mysql` package with  bluebird promise.

This will allow you to use the same mysql functions, but instead of using callback functions you can use the returned promise (and eventually [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)/[await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)) like this.

```
async handleRequest(req, res, next) {
  try {
    const loadQuery = `SELECT * FROM tr_post_load WHERE id = ${db.escape(load_id)}`;
    const loads = await db.query(sqlQuery);
    if (loads.length === 0) {
      throw new Error('Load not found');
    }
    const load = loads[0];
    const load_from_lat = load.from_lat;
    const load_from_long = load.from_long;
    const load_to_lat = load.to_lat;
    const load_to_long = load.to_long;

    const truckQuery = `SELECT * FROM tr_truck WHERE user_id != ${load.user_id} AND truck_capacity_id = ? AND body_type_id = ? AND truck_length_id = ?`;
    const trucks = await db.query(
      truckQuery,
      [ load.truck_capacity_id, load.body_type_id, load.truck_length_id ]
    );

    if(trucks.length > 0) {
      for (let a = 0; a <= trucks.length; a++) {
        if(typeof trucks[a] === 'object') {
          truck_ids.push(trucks[a].id);
        }
    }

    ...
    // more code and queries to follow
    ...
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error is '+error);
    res.status(200).send({status:'error'});
    throw error;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot bro i have implemented it and working fine.Sorry i can not upvote due to reputation restrictions

Comment: @NarmailSandhu Glad to know it helped you. You may mark this answer as accepted answer for this question instead of upvoting.

Answer (score 1):

Building on @dvsoukup's comment, you should first read through [this article about JavaScript promises](https://howtonode.org/promises). Promises were introduced to relieve this callback hell and do so wonderful.

Then, if you're on Nodejs 8 or above, you should investigate [async/await](https://blog.risingstack.com/mastering-async-await-in-nodejs/). Make sure to be okay with Promises before looking at async/await since it uses promises under the hood. You could skip this and go straight to async/await but you'll find yourself coming back to it eventually I'd imagine.

Both of these methods should stop your callback hell and make the code more readable.

Comment: Elliot Blackburn can you please modify code a little bit to use promise i am newbie to node.js i have used promises in angular but does not make sense how to use here.